# How can I make spring webflux websocket work with kotlin coroutines?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How can I make spring webflux websocket work with kotlin coroutines?

I have the following code snippet:

```
val client = ReactorNettyWebSocketClient()
val uri = URI.create("wss://websocket")

client.execute(uri) { session ->
    val handler = WebSocketImplementation(session)
    session.receive()
        .doOnNext { message ->
                handler.handleTextMessage(message) //this is a suspend function
        }
        .then()
}.block()
```

Some of the methods that handleTextMessage calls are coroutines. While I could rewrite them using Reactor, I strongly prefer coroutines. Is there a way to achieve this transition seamlessly? I am already doing it some other parts of the code, e.g:

```
session.send(Mono.just(textMessage)).awaitFirstOrNull()
```

But could not make the snippet above work with it